# onActivityResult() called prematurely

Tags: android, android-activity

I start the `Activity` (descendant of `PreferenceActivity`) from my worker activity as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1458)
        loadInfo();
}

void showSettingsDialog()
{
    startActivityForResult(new Intent().setClass(this, MyConfigure.class), 1458);
}
```

`MyConfigure` class does NOT have any `setResult()` calls. In fact, `MyConfigure` class doesn't have any code except `OnCreate()` where it loads preferences using `addPreferencesFromResource`.

Now `onActivityResult` is called with `requestCode` of `1458` prematurely, right after `MyConfigure` activity is run. Tested on 1.6 and 2.1 emulators as well as 2.1 device. Is there a call to `setResult()` buried somewhere in `PreferenceActivity`? Or how else can this premature call be explained?

Comment: An activity doesn't end on setResults(), it ends on finish().  Can you show the onCreate method of your MyConfigure activity?

Comment: Right, it doesn't. However, something does call setResult() ahead of time and I am wondering, what it is. The code of onCreate is trivial:

    public class MyConfigure extends PreferenceActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        
        }
    }

Comment: how do you think to know that setResult is called?

Comment: That is exactly what I created the question for. To find out, why onActivityResult is called prematurely.

Comment: What does the logcat output say around this period? Specifically the "ActivityManager" tag, which shows which Intents are being called.

Comment: Is anyone else experiencing this problem when both activities (the one that's launching and the one that's being launched) are singleTop? I'm just experiencing that and will probably need to hardcode something in launched activity - so let me know if someone found some workaround (working on Android 4.2.2 on Nexus 7).

Answer (score 258, accepted):

This is fixed by changing the launch mode to `singleTop`:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
```

There's a bug / feature (?) in Android, which immediately reports result (which has not been set yet) for `Activity`, declared as `singleTask` (despite the fact that the activity continues to run). If we change `launchMode` of the parent activity from `singleTask` to `singleTop`, everything works as expected - result is reported only after the activity is finished. While this behavior has certain explanation (only one `singleTask` activity can exist and there can happen multiple waiters for it), this is still a not logical restriction for me.

Comment: It seems a bug! ^^ very weird behavior!

Comment: If activity has singleTask launch mode it not need to receive results from sub-activityes using onActivityResult. Sub-activityes just call finish() and then start main activity with data intent. In main activity you must override onNewIntent method and process received intent.

Comment: launchMode="singleInstance" also causes this behaviour

Comment: Worth nothing I needed SingleTop on my _parent_ activity, not just the child

Comment: I can't believe this bug, even in Android L Preview! Wasted hours trying to figure out what was going on until I came across this. +1 for the great explanation.

Comment: The solution works but it is weird that adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP to the intent did not produce the same effect.

Comment: @jmaculate this probably depends on your activity stack and OS version.

Comment: Just removed the launchMode *singleTask* from the Activity that has to provide result data and it worked. THX

Comment: It seems did this not work for me, I tried singleTop on parent activity but to no avail. I also set the intent flag into FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP, though the request now shows the correct value but the result is always 0.

Comment: @NeonWarge what Android version do you have? The issue exposes itself differently on different versions. The best you can do is open the source code of Android itself (as I did) and find out the reason of your problem in that way.

Comment: I was doing min version = 8 and target SDK at 22. I fix the problem by circumventing that approach anyway. And most importantly, that silly mistake I made, I mixed request code with result code. They were on different param places. I didn't notice that.

Comment: thanks! I'm using SDK 22, and support v4 fragment, it happened!. you save a lot of my time!

Comment: it happens on Kitkat 4.4.4, not happening on Lolipop.

Comment: The problem is the Activity I am launching is Searchable so I can't remove this flag otherwise it totally screws over the search processing. Back to square one without a solution.

Comment: It works with all popular brand devices and all version. Saved my another day.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Didn't worj for me yet on Samsung running Kitkat.

Comment: Single instance not working for me, some Samsung Galaxy Tablet API 19. Single top works

Answer (score 21):

I solved my problem after removing `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);` before calling `fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);`.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. Is there an explanation for this somewhere?

Comment: There is an explanation for this in the docs for the flag these days "This flag can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from the activity being launched". Well its not an explanation but at least a warning!

Answer (score 5):

I just removed all my custom "android:launchMode" from my Activity and everything worked like a charm. It is not a good idea change this when you don't know EXACTLY what Android is understanding... Android is a little tricky in this way.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when the intent had the `Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND` flag set.

(Yes, that flag isn't activity-related, but I had it on all my intents as part of a shotgun solution to [a different problem](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=104308).)

Answer (score -1):

Again as in Mayra's comment, `setResult()` has nothing to do with your problem. for some reason, `MyConfigure` class finishes itself and when it happens `PreferenceActivity` just assumes that there might be a result from `MyConfigure` because that's how you wrote the code.

this also happens when you force back any activity thats started with `startActivityForResult()`...

So, I think it's better to focus on why your `MyConfigure` class is forcibly finished.

Comment: MyConfigure class does NOT finish, your guesses are wrong, sorry. If It did, there would be no question