# Android: Gallery intent returning resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery

I'm starting an intent to pick a picture from the gallery but the intent always returns with the resultcode RESULT_CANCELED. I have tried a lot of different code but nothing helps which makes me think maybe I am missing something, like putting something in the activity in the Android manifest?

My Code:

```
// The Intent
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Uri targetUri = data.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
            profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put your activity finish() code also

Comment: Hmm do you mean putting finish() after startActivityForResult? The only thing this does for me is finishing the activity (wich I don't want, I want it to return to the same activity) and still with RESULT_CANCELED.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OK so I solved this. My problem turned out to be that the onActivityResult() method was being called before the Gallery Intent had finished. I found the sollution here: [onActivityResult() called prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354955/onactivityresult-called-prematurely)

Basically, I had specified the activity to be "singleTask" in the manifest. 
Changing it to "singleTop" solved it for me.

Comment: I faced the same problem when my activity's launch mode was "singleInstance". Changing it to "singleTop" solved my problem. Thank you for sharing your solution.

Comment: Problem occuring while sending mail

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. This SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25492138/3913366 too doesn't work for me. Tested on 4.0, 5,0 and 5.1.

Comment: thanks dear , your solution worked for me , i was using "singleInstance" after changing to "singleTop" every thing is ok

Comment: Did not work for me, my solution was to remove `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Answer (score 1):

That saved my life! \0/

android:launchMode="singleTop"