# Crop image after picking up from gallery android

Tags: android, android-gallery

Want to crop image after user picks image from the Gallery.

So basically when user selects image from gallery, he should be able to crop it and when he clicks ok, image should get sent to server.

On button click, I have this code which launches gallery.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent,RESULT_TRUE);
```

Then I have this code which select image from gallery and upload it to firebase.

```
@Override
    public  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_TRUE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            dialog.show();
            Uri url = data.getData();
            StorageReference filepath = mstorage.child("photos").child(url.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile(url).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "upload done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Uri downloadurl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                    String imageUrl = downloadurl.toString();
                    Glide.with(getContext()).load(imageUrl).centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera).crossFade().into(mImage1);
                    SubscriberService subscriberService = new SubscriberService();
                    subscriberService.addItemChildList(AddImagesFragment.this, mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(), "images", imageUrl, place);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Can someone please help me with the code to crop image.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [library](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop) , May be you will get a proper solution.

Add uCrop to your Gradle first, than
To use it write this onActivityResult,

```
case IMAGE:
    UCrop.of(data.getData(), Uri.fromFile(new File(this.getCacheDir(), "IMG_" + System.currentTimeMillis())))
                    .start(YourActivity.this);
break;
```

After that handle uCrop Result in onActivityResults as (You can take a switch case to handle multiple requestcodes over there):

```
                 case UCrop.REQUEST_CROP:
                    Uri imgUri = UCrop.getOutput(data);
                    if (imgUri != null) {
                        String selectedImage = imgUri.getPath();

                       // load selectedImage into ImageView
                    } else {
                        Snackbar.make(view, R.string.str_bad_image_file, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                    break;
                case UCrop.RESULT_ERROR:
                    Snackbar.make(view, R.string.str_bad_image_file, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    break;
```

Comment: can you please tell me where exactly i have to write the ucrop code , considering the code i have shown above

Comment: sure, have a look at updated answer

Comment: thanks, but i am confused where will my existing code go?

Comment: I think you should try replacing/modifying your code with this one. You will be able to fetch Image from your code and then from the code above you will be able to handle cropping.

Comment: can you please take a look at the new problem i have
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41476946/ucrop-onactivitymethod-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to perform crop:-

```
private void performCrop(String picUri) {
        try {
            //Start Crop Activity

            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            // indicate image type and Uri
            File f = new File(picUri);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

            cropIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
            // set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            // indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            // indicate output X and Y
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 280);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 280);

            // retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, RESULT_CROP);
        }
        // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            // display an error message
            String errorMessage = "your device doesn't support the crop action!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

Refer the links, [android:select image from gallery then crop that and show in an imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490928/androidselect-image-from-gallery-then-crop-that-and-show-in-an-imageview)

[Crop an image when selected from gallery in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776438/crop-an-image-when-selected-from-gallery-in-android)

Comment: i want something which is supported for all users. I can't say we don't support crop for you :)

Comment: can you please explain what device are not supported?

Comment: It will support all device, the toast is only for that whose mobile device does not suppport crop intent. Now a days almost every device supports crop action.

Comment: ok great, and what is this url stands for

Comment: File f = new File(picUri);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
how can i get this ?

Comment: picUri will be your  Uri url = data.getData(); this url

Comment: but data.getData() is inside the OnActivityResult method. how will i get this value inside the perform crop method?

Comment: call the method performCrop(url) after your Uri url = data.getData(); and pass this url in parameter

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [library](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop). It provide basic cropping functionality and used by lots of people

Answer (score 0):

This is a well tested code, so it will definitely work. Try to use below code, for cropping the image:

    private CropImageView img_crop;
   
 private int CROP_RESULT = 3;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_crop_);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_white);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    img_crop = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_crop);
    img_crop.setInitialFrameScale(0.75f);

    img_crop.setAnimationEnabled(true);
    img_crop.setAnimationDuration(300);
    img_crop.setCropMode(CropImageView.CropMode.RATIO_3_4);
    configureDefaultImageLoader(Crop_Activity.this);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    String path = " ";
    final String type = b.getString("type");
    path = b.getString("BitmapImage");
    Log.e("Crop_Uri>>", path.toString());
    {
        try {
            InputStream image_stream = null;

            image_stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse("file://" + path.toString()));
            Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(image_stream);
            if (bitmap1 != null) {
                bitmap1.recycle();
                bitmap1 = null;
            }
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(ImageDownloader.Scheme.FILE.wrap(path.toString()), img_crop);
            //  img_crop.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
            Log.e("Image//", "//" + "yes");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //handle exception
            Log.e("ExceptionImage>>", "//" + e);
        }
    }


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          /*  Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();*/
            if (img_crop.getImageBitmap() != null) {
                Bitmap crop_bitmap = img_crop.getCroppedBitmap();
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                File dest = new File(getFilename());
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                    crop_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("croped_bitmap_uri", dest.getAbsolutePath());
                intent.setAction("ok");
                setResult(CROP_RESULT, intent);
                deleteFile();
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(Crop_Activity.this, "Crop Images Not Processed !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}

public String getFilename() {
    File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Konnect_Mom/Konnect_Mom_cropped_img");
    if (!myDirectory.exists()) {
        myDirectory.mkdirs();
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
    String mImageName = "cropped_img" + ".jpg";
    String uriSting = (myDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + mImageName);
    return uriSting;

}

public void deleteFile() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "Konnect_Mom/Konnect_Mom_cropped_img/cropped_img.jpg");
    if (file.exists()) {

        file.delete();
    }

}

public static void configureDefaultImageLoader(Context ctx) {
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(ctx).threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2).denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory().diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator()).tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .showImageOnLoading(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .showImageOnFail(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED) //filled width
            .build();
}
```

}

Just copy the above code and paste it in a class titled "CropActivity". After that in the activity where you open "**Camera**" or "**Gallery**" to fetch images, place the below code inside the "**onActivityResult()**" method:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(AddAChild.this, Crop_Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("BitmapImage", filename);
               startActivityForResult(i, CROP_RESULT);
```

That's it. Your good to go.