# onActivityResult for an Intent

Tags: android, android-activity, maps

```
else{ //this is part of some onclick listener of a button in the program
        slider.close();
        mapView.setClickable(false);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "GPS cannot retrieve your location. GPS needs clear sky or service is off. Please turn on GPS service.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        final Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnGPS);
        bt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bt.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Intent activateGps = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                //Map.this.startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                Map.this.startActivityForResult(activateGps, RESULT_OK);
                //bt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return false;
            }

        });

    }
}
```

I want to start new intent so user can enable GPS (if GPS is not activated before). I used startActivityForResult method that can respond whether Activity has resulted success or not. When success it has to do some changes on the user interface....I tried and I enable the GPS but still no changes on the UI (e.g: button does not hide). What I'm doing wrong?

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
        {
            Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnGPS);
            bt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            this.finish();
        }
        else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No GPS device or service enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG+Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Here is my onActivityResult method. Does this.finish(); finishes the current activity when it is enabled, so it initiates OnResume()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some restrictions while using `PreferenceActivity` with `startActivityForResult()` (one of these kind of discussion see [onActivityResult() called prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354955/onactivityresult-called-prematurely)).

My suggestion is: start the `PreferenceActivity` by `startActivity()` instead of `startActivityForResult()`, and then **put your code that needs to re-read the preferences in `onStart()` or `onResume()` method**, which will be invoked immediately as the Activity is on the top of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in Android... Change your

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance(or singleTasc)"
```

to

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

in your Activity which is calling the `startActivityForResult()` method and run again. It still will be working.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="True"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Please, consider adding an explanation to the answer.