# Issues with startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-activity

I have written an Activity using `Theme.Holo.Dialog` so that it works as an `AlertDialog` as a login/password notice. I've started this activity with `startActivityForResult(...)` using a request code I defined. The thing is, whenever I start the activity `onActivityResult(...)` is triggered immediately, the buttons get loaded and everything, but once I press them, even though I know the Activity is working because login does happen, there is no result sent back to the first Activity and I am calling `setResult(...)` and `finish()` after the buttons are pressed.
Thanks in advance, first time using startActivityForResult so I'm sure I must be missing something.

Main Activity:

```
.
.
.
   Intent startDialogIntent = new Intent(this,SetIdDialogAlertActivity.class);
   startDialogIntent.setAction(getString(R.string.ACTION_START_ALERT_DIALOG_ACTIVITY));
   startDialogIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.parcelable_status));
   IntentParcelable.configurationToParcelable(configuration, getBaseContext()));
   startActivityForResult(startDialogIntent,getResources().getInteger(R.integer.CREATE_USER));

.
.
.

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"returned from activity with request code " + requestCode + " and result code " + resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(requestCode == getResources().getInteger(R.integer.CREATE_USER))
            switch (resultCode){
                case RESULT_NEW_USER:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),getString(R.string.SU_CorrectPassword_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    refreshLabels(data);
                    break;
                case RESULT_WRONG_PASSWORD:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),getString(R.string.SU_WrongPassword_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
    }
```

Then on the sub-activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Logger.d(Messages.tag,System.nanoTime() + "_DIALOG_ALERT:_ON_CREATED");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_id_alertdialog);
        Logger.d(Messages.tag,System.nanoTime() + "_DIALOG_ALERT:_VIEW_INFLATED");

        SU_passwordEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SU_passwordEditText);
        Button okAlarmButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.okAlarmButton);
        Button cancelAlarmButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancelAlarmButton);

        Logger.d(Messages.tag,System.nanoTime() + "_DIALOG_ALERT:_OK_BUTTON_LOADED");
        okAlarmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Logger.d(Messages.tag,System.nanoTime() + "_DIALOG_ALERT:_OK_BUTTON_PRESSED");  
                String password = SU_passwordEditText.getText().toString();
                if(password.equals(getString(R.string.SU_password))){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),getString(R.string.SU_CorrectPassword_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    userIdEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userIdEditText);
                    String newUserName = userIdEditText.getText().toString();
                    Logger.d(Messages.tag,System.nanoTime() + "_DIALOG_ALERT:_USERNAME_" + newUserName);                
                    Configuration configuration = IntentParcelable.parcelableToConfiguration((IntentParcelable)getIntent().getParcelableExtra(getString(R.string.parcelable_status))
                            , getBaseContext());
                    configuration.setId(newUserName);
                    Intent setUserIntent = new Intent();
                    setUserIntent.setAction(getString(R.string.ACTION_ACTIVITY_NEW_ID));
                    setUserIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.INTENT_EXTRA_SENDER_NAME),"DIALOG_ACTIVITY");
                    setUserIntent.putExtra(getString(R.string.INTENT_EXTRA_NEW_CONFIG), IntentParcelable.configurationToParcelable(configuration, getBaseContext()));
                    exitActivity(RESULT_NEW_USER,setUserIntent);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),getString(R.string.SU_WrongPassword_message), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    exitActivity(RESULT_WRONG_PASSWORD);
                }
            }
        });

private void exitActivity(int exit_code, Intent data) {
    setResult(exit_code,data);
    finish();
}

private void exitActivity(int exit_code) {
    setResult(exit_code);
    finish();
}
```

Sorry for the delay in posting the code.

**[UPDATE]**

I've tried everything I can come up with and the sub-Activity is still behaving weirdly. I thought it was finishing abruptly since the parent's `onActivityResult(...)` triggers. It does not finish because it's still on top of the stack, I can see it, and it does work since anything I implement into the `Button`s gets done. But when it finishes *again* it doesn't trigger the previous one's `onActivityResult(...)` method.

**[UPDATE]**

I **MUST** be missing something. I just created a whole new `Activity`, for testing's sake, that does nothing but creating itself, setting the result to 4 and finishing. I declared it on the manifest as:

```
        <activity 
            android:name=".ActivityTest"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:process=":gui_process"
            android:exported="false">
        </activity>
```

And started it like this:

```
            Intent startDialogIntent = new Intent(this,ActivityTest.class);
            startActivityForResult(startDialogIntent,getResources().getInteger(R.integer.CREATE_USER));
```

Defined a new case statement on my `onActivityResult(...)` and it behaves just like the original activity.

Comment: I'll post it tomorrow 'cause I had to write this in a hurry.

Comment: without code, what can we say?

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/1631457) answer. Thanks to this answer,i solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354955/onactivityresult-called-prematurely). Apparently defining an Activity with `singleInstance` for its launch mode causes sub-activities to report results to parent activity immediately after being started. I restored the launch mode of the parent activity to standard and it all works now. There should be a note of some king in the developers guide.