# I am getting a NullPointerException and Failure Delivering Result exception from onActivityResult in my android app after using the camera

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, android-camera

I have looked over a lot of other questions on here but none seem to be helping me. I am writing and app where you press a button to open up the camera. That works fine but as soon as I go to save the picture it crashes and I get that error.
here is my code thus far

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int TAKE_PICTURE = 1337;
    private Uri outputFileUri;
    private int screenHeight;
    private int screenWidth;
    private ImageView background;
    private String ORIGINAL_FILE = "photo.jpg";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button take = (Button)findViewById(R.id.take);
        Button share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share);
        take.setOnClickListener(new takeInstr(this));
        ImageView background = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.background);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void startCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ORIGINAL_FILE);
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {  
            if (data != null) {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.jpg";
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options);
                int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
                int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
                String imageType = options.outMimeType;
                DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
                screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
                int heightRatio = Math.round((float) imageHeight / (float) screenHeight);
                int widthRatio = Math.round((float) imageWidth / (float) screenWidth);
                options.inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                background.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options));
            }
            else {


            }
        }
    }
}

package com.example.photoshare;



import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class takeInstr implements OnClickListener {
    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    public takeInstr(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mainActivity.startCamera();

    }

}
```

`

my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:src="@drawable/great_wall"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/take"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/take" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/share" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here are my logcat messages

```
02-18 12:42:56.266: W/dalvikvm(627): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1337, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.photoshare/com.example.photoshare.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2980)
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3023)
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1177)
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at com.example.photoshare.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:69)
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)
02-18 12:42:56.357: E/AndroidRuntime(627):  ... 11 more
02-18 12:42:56.686: I/dalvikvm(627): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-18 12:42:56.726: I/dalvikvm(627): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-18 12:42:57.047: I/dalvikvm(627): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-18 12:42:57.086: I/dalvikvm(627): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-18 12:42:59.716: I/Process(627): Sending signal. PID: 627 SIG: 9
```

I know I should do some sort of else for when it returns null but I don't know exactly what to do any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1 at com.example.photoshare.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:75)` This is not a NullPointerException... What is line 75?

Comment: What is in line 75 of your MainActivity? And it is not a Nullpointer...

Comment: sounds like you're running into a heap allocation issue (just previous to the crash Dalvik reports 3% memory free). That stops Dalvik from delivering the image correctly to your app.

Comment: @Sam and line 75 of may MainActivity is just the closing bracket of my else I'm not sure how that is causing this

Comment: @WarrenFaith hmmm guess I fixed the nullpointer and failure to deliver this is different from before but I'm still lost

Comment: Your stack trace isn't new newest then. You should clean your project and try again. Update your stack trace and code again and point us to the line where the error is thrown.

Comment: @WarrenFaith I updated the stack trace apparently its what I said I had just posted an out of date part sorry

Comment: also the error is in my if(data != null) somewhere because I only get it when I remove that if now otherwise it runs without actually doing anything

Comment: line 69 is what exactly?

Comment: @WarrenFaith background.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options));

Answer (score 1):

There are two different things in your code that could be null. The first might be an issue that the BitmapFactory can't decode the file you have provided. Also are you sure that you only want to decode `test.jpg` instead of the one taken by the camera?

The second one could be an issue with your `background` view. Based on the launch type of your activity, it [might happen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3546419/180538) that `onActivityResult()` is called before `onCreate()` which would result in an `background` variable still being null.

To dig deeper, you should assign a the decoded bitmap to a new variable and see if it is null or not and check if `background` is null...

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I'll give those a try and see if it fixes the problem.