# Tools for tracing calls to onActivityResult

Tags: android, logging, android-activity, stack-trace

What tools (log files, traces, etc) exist to debug calls to onActivityResult?   The Android documentation says that

> **onActivityResult** is called when an activity you launched exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with, the resultCode it
>   returned, and any additional data from it. The resultCode will be
>   RESULT_CANCELED if the activity explicitly returned that, didn't
>   return any result, or crashed during its operation.*

I'm trying to debug a case where apparently none of those conditions are met - onActivityResult is being called immediately without the target activity ever being involved (according to breakpoints I set in it).  The stack trace looks like this:

```
DGraphActivity.onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) line: 107 
DGraphActivity(Activity).dispatchActivityResult(String, int, int, Intent) line: 3908    
ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, List) line: 2532 
ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread$ResultData) line: 2578   
ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ResultData) line: 117 
ActivityThread$ResultData(ActivityThread$H).handleMessage(Message) line: 965    
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 130 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3687    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 842  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 600 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

The target Activity is called AddCommentActivity, which, as you can see, is not referenced in the stack trace. AddCommentActivity DOES get called just fine AFTER onActivityResult.

N.B. This is NOT a duplicate of my other question [onActivityResult being called instantly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687322/onactivityresult-being-called-instantly)   That one is to ask for a solution or workaround to the specific problem.   This one is to ask about tools and strategies for this class of problems in general.