# Android to listen back key press on the settings page if i open that from my application

Tags: android

From my activity A open a device setting page with firing the intent.can i listen back key press event on the device settings page.

e.g`Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your settings page is an `Activity`, you can override the `onBackPressed()` method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Do stuff.
}
```

or

```
@Override
protected boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Do stuff if event == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK.
}
```

*Edit.*

If you're thinking of listening (and processing) back presses in Activity A while your settings page is displayed, consider using a Fragment for your settings page, which you add  and display in Activity A.

*Edit 2 - answer to your comment:*

As far as I know, there is no way to listen for e.g. wifi on/off clicks, but what you can do is the following:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS), 0xB00B);
```

then

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0xB00B) {
        // Check if WIFI is on/off. That way you know what the user pressed.
    }
}
```

Comment: I am talking about device settings from where we on/off bluetooth,wifi etc.and i am opening this from my activity with below intent.           startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));

Comment: For Some Settings page onActivityResult method return immediately even the setting page is open.

Comment: According to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3354955/905349), what you’re experiencing might be a bug. Could you get away with just checking if e.g. WiFi or bluetooth is on, then performing required actions? It seems like a feasible solution.