# onActivityResult() called prematurely while calling Settings activity

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult, start-activity, launchmode

I'm facing the known issue `onActivityResult` getting called immediately.

I read the reason behind it on some  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354955/onactivityresult-called-prematurely)

where it is advice to change launch mode of called activity.

But in my case I'm starting(navigating to) settings activity, to let the user enable data connection.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS),
                            Constants.REQUEST_ENABLE_DATA_CONNECTION);
```

So I can't change launch mode of Settings activity.

I tried setting some flags to Intent e.g. `intent.setFlags(0);` but its not working.

Comment: Why can't you change the launch mode of the parent? I am confused on your restriction.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with your request code "Constants.REQUEST_ENABLE_DATA_CONNECTION".What is your request code value.
I think you should use zero "0" value like this.

startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);

but if you need to open wifi settings then use this code.

startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));

and see this [Setting actions link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html) for other setting actions.

I hope,this will help you.