# react-native-image-picker on Android 4.x

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-image

have anyone make the library **react-native-image-picker** work on Android below version 5?. In my case when i call to **showImagePicker** it always goes to **didCancel**.

```
const options = {
            quality: 0.7,
            maxWidth: 500,
            maxHeight: 500,
            storageOptions: {
                skipBackup: true
            },
        };

        ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {

            if (response.didCancel) {
                console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
            }
            else if (response.error) {
                console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
            }
            else if (response.customButton) {
                console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
            }
            else {
                var image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data
            }
        });
```

When i press **Choose from Library** or **Take Picture** it shows the Gallery or Camera but right away the completion function gets called with **response.didCancel = true**, is not waiting for the user to select so the completion could have the image.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

After debugging the Android part of the problem i got that the **onActivityResult()** was called prematurely. After reading a little bit in this post:

[onActivityResult() called prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354955/onactivityresult-called-prematurely)

Changing in the AndroidManifest the activity **launchMode** from **singleInstance** to **singleTop** fix the issue.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
...
```

Hope it helps if someone is struggling with something similar.