# Why is onActivityResult() of the calling activity being executed before onCreate() of the called activity?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, oncreate, onactivityresult

I have two activities 
1. MainActivity (launchMode is standard) 
2. SecondActivity (launchMode is singleTask)

When I am calling SecondActivity from MainActivity, MainActivity's onActivityResult being called before onCreate of SecondActivity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 115);
```

Here is the onActivityResult() of MainActivity.

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) { 
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
     //It is giving requestCode = 115, resultCode=0, without calling setResult anywhere.
 }
```

Then it is coming to onCreate() of SecondActivity.

I have read that, this is a bug of android in the below link. 
[onActivityResult() called prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354955/onactivityresult-called-prematurely)

Is there any solution so far, I need launchMode to be singleTask for my SecondActivity.

Comment: from the docs: *"The resultCode will be RESULT_CANCELED if the activity explicitly returned that, didn't return any result, or crashed during its operation."* - so what case was it? did you have any crash?

Comment: I didn't get any crash it just goes to onActivityResult() with resultCode RESULT_CANCELLED i.e., 0

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3546419/6698642) is in the question you linked, and it has been accepted. Have you tried this? Did it not work for you?

Comment: @TheGamer007, The answer suggests to change launchMode to singleTop which in my case is not possible. I need to use singleTask

Comment: post your `SecondActivity` code then

Comment: please check your other code, problem could be somewhere else, as it seems fine.